# I'm confused about installing WWW::Curl for Perl in Cygwin

Tags: perl, curl, cygwin

I have already installed Perl and libcurl using Cygwin's package manager. Now, I'm trying to install `WWW::Curl`. I have to specify the cURL include directory in `WWW::Curl`'s Makefile.PL, but I have no idea where to look for this. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will try to guess automatically. If it does not work, see the [README](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Curl/README).

P.S. [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP%3a%3aUserAgent) is more convenient to use.

Comment: Alas, I am on Windows, and there is no automatic installation. That's why I asked.

Comment: I am pretty sure `cpan` and `cpanm` worked fine on Cygwin the last time I checked.

Answer (score 0):

**edit:** Using your package managers own packages is often preferred when using your system perl, cygwin has a package for `perl-WWW-Curl`, install this package rather than building your own.

Most likely I think you are missing the `libcurl-devel` package. Although you mention that `libcurl` is installed, please ensure that `libcurl-devel` is installed via the cygwin package management application, and try again if required.
`WWW:Curl` will search for the correct include path, looking for `curl/curl.h`, if it cannot find the file then it might be looking in the wrong places, you'll have to do a manual install:

1. download and unpack the package from cpan
2. read the included `README` file to understand this process
3. search your cygwin installation for a file called `curl/curl.h` note the directory that it is in.
4. modify the `Makefile.PL` so that `@includes` has the directory noted above included.
5. run `perl Makefile.PL`
6. run `make && make install`

This process is essentially the same problem as the process for a native Win32/strawberry perl install, in that it doesnt know where libcurl is located. you can check the README.Win32 file for similar instructions.

The libcurl-devel package installs the `curl/curl.h` file to `usr/include/` which is a path that is already searched by `Makefile.PL`.

To however you say you have no idea where to look, locate the `curl.h` you can do the following:

```
find / -name curl.h
```

But be warned this could take a long time, you could try specific locations such as `/usr`

```
find /usr -name curl.h
```

Or even better you can look at the package contents to find the file location:

https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86%2Flibcurl-devel%2Flibcurl-devel-7.41.0-1&grep=libcurl

To echo Alexandr's answer, LWP is more convenient to use cross platform, while covering the same features, it can also do a lot more.